# How to use FirstPosition in compiled function

Tags: compile

I am trying to compile something similar to the following:

```
test = Compile[{{data, _Real, 1}}, 
  First@FirstPosition[data, _?(# > 0 &)]]
```

However I get the following error, which I don't understand:

```
Compile::part: Part specification FirstPosition[data,_?(#1>0&)][[1]] cannot be compiled since the argument is not a tensor of sufficient rank. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function.
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: The function `FirstPosition` simply will not compile to lower level code, so the only way to do this, is to write your own iterative loop from scratch. A simple `Do` loop with a `Break` should suffice.

Comment: Or a `While` loop...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sjoerd notes, you can't `Compile` pattern matching functions like `FirstPosition`. On the other hand, this will work for what you're trying to do:

```
test =
  Compile[{{data, _Real, 1}},
   MapIndexed[
    (If[# > 0, Return[#2[[1]]]]; 1) &,
    data
    ];
   -1
   ];

test@RandomReal[{-1, .01}, 100]

-1

test@RandomReal[{-1, .01}, 100]

46
```